# Facebook JS Script getting blocked across all browsers all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My React App depends so much on the Facebook Sdk which I initialized using the below code:

```
export function initFacebookSdk() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            window.FB.init({
                appId: facebookAppId,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v13.0'
            });
            window.FB.getLoginStatus(({ authResponse }) => {
                if (authResponse) {
                    //Do something
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }, true);
        };
        // load facebook sdk script
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    });
}
```

There was no issue at all with the above script on my app for more than 1 year now. Then all of a sudden few mins ago my site stopped loading in production and even on localhost. When I checked my console I saw the following message:

> The resource from “https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js” was
> blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

This is a script that has been working flawlessly for over 1 year now.

Only for this to come up all of a sudden from no where.

Please, how can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: possibly related  https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenopoly/issues/123

Comment: @James I can't really tell. I mean this script was working for months with no issues for months until the past few mins. All of a sudden, issues started from no where... This is weird

Comment: ORB is a recent change to Chrome.  Perhaps your Chrome updated itself.  https://chromestatus.com/feature/4933785622675456 - the first motivation seems to apply to your case, ie, you have a request for some javascript that is being served with text/html mime type instead of application/javascript

Comment: @James that's weird. Because I didn't update my chrome. Funny enough it is happening on my Mozilla firefox as well all of a sudden. No update

Comment: My users in production are all getting blank pages. So, does that mean they all updated their browsers. That's impossible...Something is wrong somewhere

Comment: OK, just something to consider.